# Python slice assignment should be sequence of same type?

Tags: python, slice, variable-assignment

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), it states "If the target is a slicing: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield a mutable sequence object (such as a list). The assigned object should be a sequence object of the same type."

But when I try sequence objects of different types, it seems to work:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
x[1:3] = (8,9)

print(x) # [1, 8, 9, 4, 5]

x[1:3] = "ab"
print(x) # [1, 'a', 'b', 4, 5]
```

Is this a documentation bug, or just a style suggestion, or is there something that I am not understanding correctly?

Comment: The assigned object doesn't even have to be a `Sequence`: `x[1:3] = map(str, range(2))`

Comment: Also, `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1:3]` yields `(2, 3)`, which is not a "mutable sequence object (such as a list)".

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: The question is about *assigning* to a slice. You can't do `(1,2,3,4,5)[1:3] = (6, 7)` because the tuple on the left is not a mutable sequence. You can slice immutable sequences, but not assign to them.

Comment: Yeah, that bit of documentation doesn’t really make sense. Most of the rest of the item is also too specific to built-in types; it should mention `__setitem__` like the bullet point above does, and the `slice` type.

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't something I was misunderstanding.